# Can I use static_cast to down casting?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++.
I would like to try to downcast a interface class ; although I have learned down casting may result from a bad programming design.

Some sites say "use dynamic_cast to check validity of down casting". However, in my case, I don't need to check the validity because I can guarantee it is a down casting from a base class to a derived class. I tried dynamic_cast and static_cast in the following example code. And they works well.

Can I use static_cast when I can guarantee it is a valid down casting?

Example code :

```
struct Parent_Interface {
    virtual ~Parent_Interface() {};
    virtual void print(void) = 0;
};

struct Child : public Parent_Interface {
    virtual ~Child() {};
    void print(void) override {
        std::cout << "Child::print()." << std::endl;
    }
};

void StaticDownCastToChild(Parent_Interface& parent_interface) {
    auto& child0 = static_cast<Child&>(parent_interface);
    std::cout << "StaticDownCastToChild : ";
    child0.print();
}

void DynamicDownCastToChild(Parent_Interface& parent_interface) {
    auto& child0 = dynamic_cast<Child&>(parent_interface);
    std::cout << "DynamicDownCastToChild : ";
    child0.print();
}

void test_static_cast_down_cast(void) {
    Child c;
    StaticDownCastToChild(c);
    DynamicDownCastToChild(c);
}
```

Output of executing test_static_cast_down_cast().

```
StaticDownCastToChild : Child::print().
DynamicDownCastToChild : Child::print().
```

Comment: Using `static_cast` is the recommended way. For just about *any* cast.

Comment: CRTP is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Some sites say...

Don't mind what *some sites say*. The standard ([working draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#2)) says:

> An lvalue of type “cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to cv2 D”, where D is a class derived from B, if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1.

Also, it contains an example that is almost the same you are asking for:

```
struct B { };
struct D : public B { };
D d;
B &br = d;

static_cast<D&>(br);            // produces lvalue to the original d object
```

Therefore I would say that yes, you can do that.

There are plenty of uses for such a cast. As an example, CRTP idiom is a case where you know exactly what's the type of the derived class and you don't want to check if the cast is *valid* through the use of `dynamic_cast`. Your case is probably another one of those (it's hard to say without the original code).

Comment: thank you for answering. Yes I would like to make a class ContainerAny through a interface class. And I would like to convert the element of container to the original class by using information which the interface can provide, for example, element.classType(); Thank you very much again.

Comment: @mora I'm glad to help. Anyway there are plenty of better solutions to do that than a `classType` method. My two cents. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> Some sites say "use dynamic_cast to check validity of down casting". However, in my case, I don't need to check the validity because I can guarantee it is a down casting from a base class to a derived class.

Correct.

> Can I use static_cast when I can guarantee it is a valid down casting?

Yes.

In fact, you *should*, as it is "free". `dynamic_cast` often involves some runtime overhead.

However, you may wish to put a `dynamic_cast` in an `assert` alongside it, for good measure. Remember that this will have no effect on your release build, but may aid you during debugging if something goes horribly wrong. Some of the most satisfying moments of my career have involved a well-placed `assert` firing unexpectedly, resulting in a very quick bug-fixing process; the alternative can be months of pain and guesswork!

Comment: Thank you for answring. I would like to make a class ContainerAny which holds some classes whose base class are a interface class. And I would like to convert the element of the container to the original class using a type information from interface; for example, element.type(). So I hope I can guarantee it is valid downcasting after the first valid test.

Comment: @mora: Perfect use case.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use static_cast when I can guarantee it is a valid down casting?

**Yes,** you can. That said, situations where you *know* the cast will be valid but you can't specify the more-specific type (e.g. `Child&`) shouldn't come up very often. I can't think of a reason that you'd use `Parent_Interface&` instead of `Child&` when you *know* you're always passing the latter.

Comment: Common when you have an entity registration interface of some kind and you need to "undo" the type erasure based on some non-type key.

Comment: @Caleb : I try to make a class ContainerAny which holds some classes whose base class are a interface class. And I would like to convert the element of the container to the original class.

Comment: Called it... ;)